# What is the key shortcut to make Intellij show implicit methods

Tags: intellij-idea

What is the key shortcut to make Intellij show implicit methods. In the IDE I want to permanently see which `implicit` is in scope and will be used.

Answer (score 1):

just found - `ctrl`+`alt`+`shift`+`=`. Looked up up in `File->settings` and searched for `implicit.